# Partial View model data missing on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a view which contains a partial view.  I need to pass a value from the parent view into the partial view.  I do this like so:

```
 <div>
   @Html.Partial("_DrugScan", new TIMS.Models._DrugScan() { ASNID = Model.ASNID })
</div>
```

The "_DrugScan" class contains only two properties, the ASNID and a UPC.  The partial view uses a form to fill in the UPC like so:

```
@model TIMS.Models._DrugScan

@*@Scripts.Render("~Scripts/ScanDrugPost.js")*@



<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DrugScan", "Receive", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.Label("Scan Drug UPC")
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBoxFor(x => x.UPC).Mask("000000000000").PromptChar("-").HtmlAttributes(new {@id="UPC_textbox"})
            </dd>
        </dl>

    }

</div>
```

The problem I have is that when I submit the form, the UPC property is filled out but the ASNID is back to null/default.  I can hit a breakpoint in the page and see that the ASNID is getting set appropriately but is lost on submission.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit a form, it will fill the request form data with the values of the inputs inside the form.

The only input you have on your form is the one for UPC field.

What you need is to add an input which will store your other field (ASNID) inside the form. I assume that you don't want to show this value to the user so you can use a Hidden field.

```
@model TIMS.Models._DrugScan

@*@Scripts.Render("~Scripts/ScanDrugPost.js")*@

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DrugScan", "Receive", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ASNID)

        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.Label("Scan Drug UPC")
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBoxFor(x => x.UPC).Mask("000000000000").PromptChar("-").HtmlAttributes(new {@id="UPC_textbox"})
            </dd>
        </dl>

    }

</div>
```

Comment: Ohhhh... I figured it would submit the entire model that is the datacontext for the form.  I was going to try the hidden field but I didn't think it was that simple... Turns out it is though, thanks!

Comment: @user1278533: you may want to learn a little about HTML forms before proceeding. ASP.NET MVC doesn't hide the workings of HTML from you the way that ASP.NET Webforms did, so you need to know what's going on.